# Loop Tools > Circle

Tags: vertices

[image: This what's happening, note; the 'rogue' vertex at the very bottom]I'm making the neck of a mesh figure, when I click, loop tools > circle, I get two distorted circles instead of two semi-circles. The front part of the neck is ok, but back of the neck is the problem. Also, at that point there is a 'rogue' vertex which I can't move or delete? (it's not origin object) The screen shot with the red tick is what I'm after.

Comment: Hi, it appears your screenshot didn't make it into the post.

Comment: Ok, I added the image, Thx